# every time I backup my mysql database it needs to repair tables

Tags: mysql

I have a manual backup script for my CMS.

Every other time I have created a backup, it says it needs to

Repair a table or multiple tables ?

Is there something that I am doing wrong in day to day activity -- that is causing this ? Is the database corrupt ?

Here is the actual warning:

```
    REPAIR TABLE table_one EXTENDED

    status: OK


    ------------------------------------------------------------

    REPAIR TABLE table_two EXTENDED

    status: OK


    ------------------------------------------------------------

    REPAIR TABLE table_three EXTENDED

    status: OK


    ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: "it says" ... what is "it?" ... where and when are you seeing this output?  Also, does your backup script use `mysqldump`?

Comment: I am looking at the source now, it doesn't say that it uses mysqldump ?

Comment: Specifically how do you do the backup?  (if there's a script, post that).